# Evaluate [$-x^{n+1} e^{-x} ]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}$

Tags: integration, limits

Evaluate the following:

[$-x^{n+1} e^{-x} ]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}$, where $n$ is any integer greater than 1

Any help?

Comment: Do you know what $f(x)\big]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}$ means?

Comment: Yes, $f(\infty) - f(0)$

Comment: What are $f(\infty)$ and $f(0)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}-x^{n+1}e^{-x}
&=-(2n+2)^{n+1}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{x}{2n+2}}e^{\large-\frac{x}{2n+2}}\right)^{2n+2}\\
&=-(2n+2)^{n+1}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\tfrac{x}{2n+2}}e^{\large-\frac{x}{2n+2}}\right)^{2n+2}\\
&=-(2n+2)^{n+1}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{e^u}\right)^{2n+2}\\
\end{align}
$$
Then use the fact that $e^u\ge1+u$.